# Who are the video game dogs in this GIF by animator Paul Robertson?

Tags: character-identification, video-games, crossovers

Who are all the dogs in the GIF below by [Paul Robertson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paul_Robertson_(animator)) (an animator involved in various video games and animated shows)? I believe they are all from various video games, but please correct me if I am wrong. I can only identify the [*Duck Hunt*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_Hunt) dog (fifth from left) and [Rush](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Mega_Man_characters#Rush), Mega Man’s dog (tenth from left).

[image: GIF of video game dogs by Paul Robertson]

GIF source: http://paulrobertson.mechafetus.com/barkbarkbark.gif — This was Paul Robertson’s official site. I can’t find the original webpage or blog post where this was originally posted. I believe this GIF is from around 2011 ([2011 Reddit /r/gaming post where this GIF was posted](https://www.reddit.com/r/gaming/comments/hsfan/vg_dogs_by_paul_robertson/)).

Answer (score 39, accepted):

This artwork is called **Bark Bark Bark**. A print can be purchased [here](https://www.gallerynucleus.com/detail/15132/).

From left to right:

> Chihuahua from God hand
> Zombie dog from Resident Evil
> K.K. Slider from Animal Crossing
> Iggy from JoJo's Bizarre Adventure
> Dog from Duck Hunt
> Hewie from Haunting Ground
> Amaterasu from Okami
> Chibiterasu from Okamiden
> Angelo from Final Fantasy VIII
> Rush from Megaman
> Mira from Silent Hill 2
> Dog from Harvest Moon
> Koromaru from Persona 3
> Poochyena from Pokémon
> Animal Contra from Neo Contra

Answer (score 10):

From left to right:

1. Don't know yet
2. A zombie dog from *Resident Evil*
3. K.K. Slider from *Animal Crossing*
4. Iggy from *JoJo's Bizarre Adventure*
5. The *Duck Hunt* dog
6. Hewie from *Haunting Ground*
7. Amaterasu from *Ōkami*
8. Chibiterasu from *Ōkamiden*
9. Don't know yet
10. Rush from *Mega Man*
11. Mira from the *Silent Hill* series
12. Don't know yet
13. Koromaru From *Persona 3*
14. Poochyena from *Pokémon*
15. Don't know yet

Comment: It may be a little generic, but 12 would match how the dog from harvest moon was usually pictured in the 2000s